# GPS Availability check

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, gps

How to identify whether GPS is available in Windows Mobile Device. Can it be verified by any registry setting, Intermediate drivers are present in non GPS phones also. what is the best way to identify (programetically, checking any folder or from registry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Windows Mobile 6.5 and up, you can get advantage of [GPS Intermediate Driver query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202086.aspx)

Comment: Tamir, you point to the whole GPS driver, is there a specific 'query' ?

Comment: @Henk - if you click `reference` then `functions` on the left, you can get to `GPSGetDeviceState` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202076.aspx. That should tell you everything you need to know about the GPS or lack thereof.

Comment: you do not need "specific driver" for this. even generic one for Windows Mobile 6.5 will work

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check if the `GPSOpenDevice` function would return `null` ?